# component selector is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular7

I have 2 modules `AppModule` and `MyArtModule` with some components declared in it.

when I tried to use `ConfirmComponent` selector in `GraphicsComponent` it's working fine, but when I tried to use `ConfirmComponent` selector in `MyArtComponent` it's throwing an error `'artifi-confirm-alert' is not a known element:`

> 'artifi-confirm-alert' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'artifi-confirm-alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'artifi-confirm-alert' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

- AppModule

  - GraphicsComponent
  - ConfirmComponent
  - MyArtModule

    - MyArtComponent

---

AppModule Code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GraphicsComponent,
    ConfirmAlertComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyArtModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

---

MyArtModule Code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyArtComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MyArtService
  ],
  exports: [
    MyArtComponent
  ]
})
```

---

**replicated issue code** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/skdroid-childmodule-in-child-component

I've created `OneModule` with `OneComponent` and `TwoModule` with `TwoComponent`.

`<app-one></app-one>` and `<app-two></app-two>` are accessible in AppComponent.

but unable to access `<app-two></app-two>` in AppOne component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access parent module component in the child module component. Create a shared module and add component in it.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ConfirmComponent],
  exports: [ConfirmComponent],
})

export class SharedModule {
}
```

And add it in the AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GraphicsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyArtModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

And import it in your ArtModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [ConfirmAlertComponent],
  exports: [
    ConfirmAlertComponent
  ]
})
export class MyArtModule { }
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mn-angular-shared-module)

Comment: I created a new module for confirm component and imported in app module but still getting the same error, tried to replicate in stackbliz link is in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your ConfirmComponent and GraphicsComponent are in same Module! So they knew each other! 
But you're trying to use that ConfirmComponent to another component which is in another module( in your case: MyArtModule ) which don't know whether that component exists!

You have to export ConfirmComponent to make it enable to all over application!

Add ConfirmComponent in exports Array of AppModule

```
exports: [
  ConfirmComponent
]
```

Comment: added ConfirmComponent in an export array of AppModule but still same error

Comment: Could u send what's inside confirm-component.ts file?

Comment: nothing, it's just a new component. please check question I've added a link to replicate issue.